# Location of merkleroot per block / block header

Tags: monerod-commands

Is it possible to acquire the merkleroot per block with rpc command or core command?

Why is the merkleroot not included in the block header in the [cns003.txt](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns003.txt)?

I see the transaction hashes are included in some rpc responses so must I calculate merkleroot manually?

Answer (score 1):

The merkle root hash is used when creating the block hash. This is in the `block_header` as returned from the daemon RPC method `get_block`.

Comment: I thought the block hash was the block identifier:

Comment: 5. Calculation of Block Identifier

   The identifier of a block is the result of hashing the following data
   with Keccak:

      - size of [block_header, Merkle root hash, and the number of 
        transactions] in bytes (varint)

      - block_header,

      - Merkle root hash,

      - number of transactions (varint).

   The goal of the Merkle root hash is to "attach" the transactions
   referred to in the list to the block header: once the Merkle root
   hash is fixed, the transactions cannot be modified.

Comment: For block with height of  912345 and block hash e22cf75f39ae720e8b71b3d120a5ac03f0db50bba6379e2850975b4859190bc6 I see only a coinbase transaction with hash  c7da3965f25c19b8eb7dd8db48dcd4e7c885e2491db77e289f0609bf8e08ec30.  In bitcoin if there is only a coinbase transaction then the coinbase transaction is used as merkleroot but this does not seem to be the case for Monero? When I take the Monero 912345 coinbase hash byteswap it, concatenate it with itself decode from hex, double hash it with sha256 and encode to hex doesn't result in the block hash?

Comment: Block hash is the block ID which also is derived from merkle root hash.

Comment: Your example of trying to recreate block hash is flawed in a couple of ways. The merkle root hash is just the tx hash if there is only 1 tx, but to get to the block hash you need to follow the steps in the paper you linked. There is no mention of sha256 for starters. You need to use Keccak.

Comment: ok, so is the only way to get the merkle root for block with more than one transaction(coinbase) to calculate it myself using keccak. The RPC method get_block doesn't contain the merkleroot from what i can tell unless it is in the blob?

Comment: Keccak won't calculate a merkle root, you have to generate/calculate the merkle root before hashing. `get_block` returns everything needed to calculate the merkle root hash (as outlined in the linked cns003 spec).

Comment: h[i] = H(h[2*i] || h[2*i+1]) 
        where 1 <= i <= m-1 or 3*m-n <= i <= 2*m-1.
      h[i] = H(tx[i-m])
        where m <= i <= 3*m-n-1
      h[i] = H(tx[i-4*m+n])
        where 6*m-2*n <= i <= 4*m-1.

   Where H is the Keccak function that is used throughout CryptoNote, Why won't Keccak calculate the merkle root?

Comment: Seems to me the merkleroot is whole thing holding blockchain together why is is not in the block header and must be calculated manually using tx hashes.

Comment: "Why won't Keccak calculate the merkle root?" Because it's a hashing function, nothing more.

Comment: "Seems to me the merkleroot is whole thing holding blockchain together why is is not in the block header and must be calculated manually using tx hashes". It is, it's hashed in the block ID (hash). If anything changes in the block (or it's txs), when validating a block ID it would not match. This is what makes the blocks immutable (tamperproof).

Comment: ok that is what i am asking. So i use the keccak function to hash transactions hashes to get the merkle root. This is what I am asking. Say I pick any block, say block height 542343 is the only way to get the merkleroot from calculating it manually

Comment: "So i use the keccak function to hash transactions hashes to get the merkle root" No. The block hash (it's ID) is defined in the cns003 doc you linked to at section 5:
"The identifier of a block is the result of hashing the following data with Keccak:
      - size of [block_header, Merkle root hash, and the number of transactions] in bytes (varint)
      - block_header,
      - Merkle root hash,
      - number of transactions (varint)."

Keccak is a hashing function.

Comment: An example of calculating the merkle root is defined here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/9f24e57dc225a26583571792caa0a948904ef21c/src/crypto/tree-hash.c#L70